# Why does my 1980 Fiat Spyder keep cutting out?

Tags: fuel-pump, fiat

I have a 1980 Fiat Spyder. It starts fine, but occasionally it cuts out - just dies. I can re-start it again OK. We had a new relay installed, but even the mechanic is out of ideas.

Comment: Loose connections? faulty coil? All need checking.

Comment: Fiats from that era are known to be temperamental, with dodgy electrical systems.